# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/encryption/StringEncryptor

Tags: java, tomcat, jasypt

I am trying to read a encrypted value from a file using jasypt package. 
When I am reading the file using a demo code it is able to properly without any error.But when I am deploying the package on tomcat, it is not able to locate the stringEncryptor class.

I have checked and the package is present in WEBINF/lib file folder
[image]

Comment: So there's a file named something like `WEB-INF/lib/jasypt-1.9.2.jar`?